# String date time format

Tags: c#, xml, api, datetime

I am using the Vimeo API and I want to convert the string <upload_date> to a short date format, {0:d} or {0:dd/mm/yyyy}.

This is my code but it doesn't seem to be working for me.

```
    select new VimeoVideo
            {
                Date = String.Format("{0:d}",(item.Element("upload_date").Value)),
            };
        return Vids.ToList();
    }

    public class VimeoVideo
    {
        public string Date { get; set; }
    }
```

Comment: what format is item.Element("upload_date").Value in?

Comment: Are you 100% certain that `item.Element("upload_date").Value` is a `DateTime` structure?

Comment: Probably an additional casting of item.Element("upload_date").Value to DateTime solve your problem

Comment: In what way does it not seem to be working?  Not getting the correct format, compile error, runtime exception?

Comment: i think its a string but im not 100% sure of that. this is what its giving me in the xml.
<upload_date>2009-11-04 16:13:17</upload_date>

Comment: Not getting an error its just not changing the format?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As Oleg suggested you can try to parse your value to DateTime and then format it (use try catch if needed). That should work (not 100% sure since I don't know what item's type is).

```
var myDate = DateTime.Parse(item.Element("upload_date").Value);
Date = String.Format("{0:d}", myDate);
```

http://msdn.microsoft.com/it-it/library/1k1skd40(v=VS.80).aspx

Answer (score 0):

Just verify the type of the Value property.. The above string formatter works for System.DateTime structure.. I assume in your case its string type object. According to the given sample date time string i have written this code.. Try out this.

```
CultureInfo provider = CultureInfo.InvariantCulture;
var format = "yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss";
var dt = DateTime.ParseExact(item.Element("upload_date").Value, format, provider);
Date = string.Format("{0:d}", dt);
```

Hope it works..